# How to use programming logic (e.g. JS) on Google Forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-forms

Ok, maybe this question is not extremely well-formulated, but I have a problem and I want to solve it, hence the existence of this question. There is a Google Forms form in which, in its current state, users answer questions and, after they have answered such questions, they themselves have to compute their results (a simple algorithm) (it's, to be precise, it's a Vark-style questionnaire (not that it matters)). That is cumbersome and prone to error, so I am in charge of making the form itself compute the thing and show it to the user afterwards.

So I figured I just gotta be able to program an output based on inputs of Google Forms. Such an output would ideally dinamically change on the screen (as the user changes his answers), but it can also be shown after the questionnaire has been answered. What is the way to go? I searched a bit about it and it seems one could use Google App Scripts to make an add-on for forms... Is this overkill or the way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is already an inbuilt system as to where the Google Forms form calculates the score. However, there is a catch , the questions need to be in MCQ format .

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, sorry, it's not a score per-se. It's a description of how a given person best learns, based on answers to descriptive questions (what would you do in scenario X, scenario Y etc.). So I'm not sure a simple system would suffice, as I would need to actually code the algorithm and show it to the user.

Comment: But hey, that could suffice. The questions are, indeed in MCQ. But there are tons of possible combinations, so I would have to code a simple external program that would list every possible combination and its output and then manually feed that into the system. Is there another way that you know of? Thank you, by the way!

Comment: This would require you to go way above and beyond the scope of javascript and indulge you to use python. It would basically have to be something related to deep learning and running the python application along with say , php , in the background.

Comment: By tons of possible combinations I mean... It's simple logic, but there are like 10 questions with 5 multiple choice answers each. It would be... (2^5)*10 different combinations, I guess (320). But if that works, I guess I can lose an hour or two manually feeding the inputs and outputs to that system you described.

Comment: Where can I access that inbuilt system? It's probably right in front of me there in the forms gui...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjfOwVpJcq8
Visit this link and I am sure , it'll help you.

Comment: That has to do more with quizzes, I guess... The questionnaire I have is not a quiz per-se, it's a normal one. I just want to display a message based on the answers the user provided. I think I'll have to take a look on Google App Scripts. But thank you anyway!

Comment: As to python, python can do anything js does (both are turing complete). And deep learning, I thought you were being sarcastic at first, to be honest. All I want is, if possible, to use the already available Google tools to run a simple algorithm based on forms' responses and show the result to the user.

Comment: I'm unsure whether Google App Scripts is able to modify the form or only modifies the Google Forms. Please, someone experienced with that?

Comment: Based on what I've read, one cannot edit things on the form itself programmatically, only after the response has been sent. Is this correct? If so, is it possible, after the user has sent its response, to do logic with his response and show a personalized message to him?

Comment: Ok, I already know it's possible to solve my problem by informing the user an email has been sent with his classification, and triggering a Google App Script when the form is answered (such script would get the form's response, generate the appropriate output based on it and send it to the user's email). Does anyone know whether there is a way to change the submit response itself, such that no email is needed?

Comment: Solved. To anyone having a similar objective as I had, the way I did it was basically what I commented above. Use Google App Scripts to set a trigger so that a JS function will be called every time a form is submitted, then code your way from there (you have access to a class able to send emails from your Google account, another one you can use to edit spreadsheets, an object that represents the answers to the form etc.).